# Appending rows to csv using dict_writer

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am appending rows to an existing csv file with the following code:

```
counter=1
for thepage in newpages:    
    web_page = urllib2.urlopen(thepage)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.read())

    fieldnames=["var1", "var2","var3","var4","var5", "var6", "var7"]
    if counter==1:
            f = open('file.csv', 'wb')  
            my_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
            my_writer.writeheader()
            f.close()

    variables={ele:"MISSING" for ele in fieldnames}
    variables['var1']=str(counter)
    variables['var2']=soup.find_all('strong')[0].text
    variables['var3']=soup.find_all('p')[1].text[0]
    variables['var4']=soup.find_all('p')[1].text[1]
    variables['var4']=soup.find_all('p')[2].text
    variables['var6']=soup.find_all('p')[6].text
    variables['var7']=soup.find_all('p')[7].text
    print variables
    with open('file.csv', 'r+b') as f:
        header = next(csv.reader(f))
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
        dict_writer.writerow(variables) 
   counter+=1
```

where the "variables" dictionary is created within a loop.The loops continue running with no problem but when I look at the csv file it had stopped appending  rows more or less in the 30th row. I already checked and it is not a problem with the "variables" dictionary and even when I change the file and use other variables it fails more or less in the same row. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show us more code? We would need an [MCVE] , the code you posted alone would not be sufficient to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code? Where are you setting counter? Could it be possible that after the 30th row you are resetting counter to 1 ?

Comment: I forgot to put it in the question (I updated again). It is not a problem with any of the dictionary or variables. I put a print inside the loop and it seems all completely ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, I think, that you are overwriting the file each time. It is being opened with mode `'r+b'` and this positions the file pointer to the beginning of the file. Subsequent writes therefore overwrite the previous contents of the file.

You can open the file in append mode which can be done using mode `'ab'`.

Having said that, it is not necessary to continually open the file, nor to output the CSV headers within the body of the for loop. I suggest the following:

```
import csv

counter=1
fieldnames=["var1", "var2","var3","var4","var5", "var6", "var7"]

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:    
    my_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
    my_writer.writeheader()

    for thepage in newpages:    
        web_page = urllib2.urlopen(thepage)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.read())

        variables={ele:"MISSING" for ele in fieldnames}
        variables['var1']=str(counter)
        variables['var2']=soup.find_all('strong')[0].text
        variables['var3']=soup.find_all('p')[1].text[0]
        variables['var4']=soup.find_all('p')[1].text[1]
        variables['var4']=soup.find_all('p')[2].text
        variables['var6']=soup.find_all('p')[6].text
        variables['var7']=soup.find_all('p')[7].text
        print variables
        my_writer.writerow(variables) 
        counter+=1
```

Comment: You mean changing  open('file.csv', 'r+b') as f: to with open('file.csv', 'ab') as f:?

Comment: The suggested alternative looks like a better approach — I don't think the `csv` module's readers and writers really support the file's current position begin changed without its knowledge. P.S. The `counter` probably isn't needed any more...

Comment: @user2246905 : Yes, `open('file.csv', 'ab')` will open the file in binary _append_ mode.

Comment: @user2246905 : why are you still trying to read the file? Anyway, try `a+b` which will open for reading and writing. I suggest that you read the documentation for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: You were right the only problem was changing 'r+b' for 'a+b'